# How to access code behind on MasterPage for ControlParameter

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, controlparameter

I'm trying to find this `String` in my code behind on my masterpage, however since my ControlId="__Page" it's looking for the string on the child page instead of the master page
`<asp:ControlParameter Name="WhereClause" ControlID="__Page" PropertyName="ViewUserPageNavigationWhereClause"`

How do you access the ControlId of the behind code of the masterpage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

[Bind a ControlParameters to any public page property](http://blog.falafel.com/Blogs/adam-anderson/2008/03/11/Bind_a_ControlParameter_To_Any_Public_Page_Property)

I hope it helps!